# Values not Passed from Form Using Jade Template

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I want to update the email field in following when new value is submitted from the jade template. Here the username is taken as the primary key.
But in here the data is not updated. it just redirects without changing the values

> Route/Index.js

```
router.post('/edit/:id',function(req,res){
    MongoClient.connect(db, function(err, db) {

    if(err) { throw err; } 

    var collection = db.collection('usercollection'); 
    var username = req.params.id;
    var userEmail = req.body.email;

    collection.update({'username':username},{ $set: {'email ': userEmail } },function(err, result) { 
      if(err) { throw err; } 

      db.close(); 


      res.redirect('/userlist'); 

    });
  });
});
```

> View/editPage.jade

```
extends layout

    block content 
        h1= title
        each user, i in data
            form#forAddUser(name="adduser", method="post",action="/edit/user.username")
                label#username= user.username
                input#email(type="text",value="#{user.email}",name="email")
                button#btnSubmit(type="submit") submit
```

Comment: Should that not be `action="/edit/#{user.username}"`

Comment: @NeilLunn i changed that as above. but the problem remains same

Comment: I notice you are using `Router`. Are you positive you are chained to "root"? Or does this in fact chain to another URI? Such as `/api`. You need to show the full context of the code where the route is resolved in your question. And check your rendered output to see that the actual "action" value is using the `username` value.

Comment: @NeilLunn  aha i found it. in the query where there is email i typed it as 'email '  when i removed the space inside quotes as 'email' it worked   :)                           thank you Neill